# Duplicate localized resource "/Localizable.strings" found xcode 6.1

Tags: ios, localization, xcode6, xcode6.1, xliff

I am adding  multiple languages to an iOS application from .xliff files. On the first import, all works as planned and everything comes is and works great. On the second, however, it will tell me:

```
Duplicate localized resource "XXX/Localizable.strings" found
```

It appears that it isn't grouping the files correctly, even though they are in the appropriate locations in finder.

Any ideas?

Comment: Check the TARGET value of the xliff file you are importing. Maybe they are the same.

Comment: Great thought, but the source and target tags ars appropriately labeled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't get it to work properly but here is my work around:
I would import language 1, watch the files get added to the project and then remove references in the Xcode project (Note I didn't delete them from the disk). This makes it Xcode doesn't know they exist in the project but they are still there in the project folder in finder.

I did this for every language but the last one. The last language I clicked on the created localizable.strings file and click "Add files to the project" and added back all of the files I had previously removed the references.

I assume this is just some sort of bug but that is the only way I figured around they issue.

Comment: For storyboard strings, uncheck the right-pane boxes under Localization to remove the references.