# Why does Xcode say "Duplicate localized resource info.plist found" when I try to import or export localizations?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, localization

I'm sure there is something messed up in the project file but I have not been able to find it (it's a legacy project new to me).

If I remove the reference to info.plist in the project, then it will successfully import and export, which is a workaround, but not ideal (obviously, although it's easy to revert).

I have searched for duplicate info.plist files and there are none that I can see (there actually are for the watchkit extension and app, but those are named differently anyway).

The actual name of my info.plist is like myapp-info.plist, but it is correctly named in the build settings--the project builds fine.

I have googled the heck out of this and can't find any other reports so I'm really stuck. Next step is to burn an Apple tech support request and when I do, I'll report back, but I thought I would ask the SO community first.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried spelunking in the pbxproj file to see if there are multiple references there?

Comment: Yes, I did open it in a text editor and found no other occurrences. Good idea though.

Comment: did you solve it? How?

Comment: Not solved, cause never found. Problem didn't occur in new project that replaced old one.

Answer (score 5):

I had this same error.  To fix it, I had to localize the *-info.plist file.  Select the info.plist file and click "Localize..." in the File Inspector pane.

Comment: Hmm, that is in direct opposition to Apple's docs which say to not localize the info.plist file itself.

Comment: Could you link to the documentation?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AboutInformationPropertyListFiles.html

> Localized values are not stored in the Info.plist file itself. Instead, you store the values for a particular localization in a strings file with the name InfoPlist.strings.

Comment: This works for me, but it's true that its not the right way to localise Info.plist strings, so after doing the localisation work I rollback to right localisation way for this file.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you have solved this problem but I had the same issue. I think it happens when you change the project name and the build settings do not do its job to reflect the change. The Test info.plist refers to the same target original plist and seems to cause this problem.

Go to build settings in your project>Target>Project-name-Tests>Build Settings. Then locate Packaging>Info.plist File and change the folder to project-nameTest/Info.plist.

I hope this does the trick.

Answer (score 2):

My experience was different here. I have multiple targets that all use the same code base. At some point (ostensibly due to a bad manual merge) the Info.plist setting in the Build Settings tab got set to the same value for multiple targets.

[image]

Once I straightened all of those out, I was able to export the Xliff file without any issues.

Comment: This just bit me too.  We had added a target for an ad-hoc build and duplicated the old target.  It builds fine but choked up the XLIFF exporter.  Renaming the plist file in the ad-hoc target - even to an invalid name - and then doing the export worked.  Interesting that the export couldn't handle 2 targets with the same plist name but it could handle one target with a non-existent file!

Answer (score 0):

I was receiving this error message in Xcode 7.3.1 and what I did was create a new empty project in Xcode and model my info.plist files after that. This involved:

- renaming my [app name]-Info.plist file to Info.plist and moving it out of Supporting Files to the main folder
- going to project target (General tab) and selecting the renamed file. There should be a button for 'Choose Info.plist File'
- doing similarly in the Tests folder. I don't think this step is necessary to fix the error but did it for consistency.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at this question on SO - [Duplicate localized resource "/Localizable.strings" found xcode 6.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27361924/duplicate-localized-resource-localizable-strings-found-xcode-6-1) - and I was able to export to .xliff successfully when I removed reference to the ProjectName-Info.plist file.

I re-added the file, and the project compiled successfully. You have to remove the reference again every time you want to export/import and re-add the file again.

I wasn't able to import updated .xliff files successfully, but I'm thinking on using just Localizable.strings file moving forward. I'm just happy that Project -> Editor -> Export for localization finally worked!

Comment: If you look at my original post on this topic, you'll see that I named that as a workaround :)